# How to run Java program from any arbitrary directory inside Terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I saw some other similar posts, but they didn't seem to answer my question.

I have a package of java files, and the java functions inside one file call java functions from a different file. Right now I am limited to run my program from the parent directory of gitlet as shown in the screenshot. Is there a way to run my java program from any arbitrary directory?

P.S. I am hoping to get a solution that can be done just inside terminal.

[screenshot of package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TI58.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From anywhere

```
java -cp path/to/my/compiled/classes/directory1 fully.qualified.name.of.BootstrapClass
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to run my java program from any arbitrary directory?

Yes, you can add the base directory that contains the compiled `.class` files to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.